# mapped drives stop working and need to be remapped

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, shared-folders

This is a weird situation. I have a desktop PC with Windows 10 and a Windows Server 2012 R2 from which I have mapped shares onto the desktop. Quite often it happens that drives become unavailable or disconnected. Maybe it happens after the server reboot. But when I click on the drive it asks me for credentials, I enter them and it doesn't accept it! When I try via command line I get error 1219 which doesn't make sense, because I mapped those drives using the same username, so no, there is no multiple users as the error says!

```
C:\Users\vzure>net use
Nová připojení budou zapamatována.


Stav       Místní     Vzdálené                    Síťové

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nedostupné   X:        \\vitas-server\c$         Microsoft Windows Network
Odpojen      Y:        \\vitas-server\e$         Microsoft Windows Network
Odpojen      Z:        \\vitas-server\d$         Microsoft Windows Network
Příkaz byl úspěšně dokončen.


C:\Users\vzure>net use x: \\vitas-server\c$
Zadejte uživatelské jméno pro vitas-server: administrator
Zadejte heslo pro vitas-server:
Zadejte uživatelské jméno pro vitas-server: administrator
Zadejte heslo pro vitas-server:
Došlo k systémové chybě 1219.
```

the solution is to remove the mappings and map them again, but I find it quite stupid and illogical...

Comment: Not an answer, obviously, just a warning comment. Windows Server 2012 or R2 is EoL since last October and Windows 10 is supported until 2025 only. You should start thinking about proper upgrades now. Or do the smart thing and use Linux.

Comment: Do you connect using VPN also? If so, VPN credentials will be passed to the network shares, and if they are different from what you normally use, it will disconnect you. The only way to fix this is to get the VPN username and password changed so they match the network credentials. Ideally a RADIUS server is used so they get the login data from the same location.

Comment: If it's a local administrator account, you might want to try using the format `net use x: \\vitas-server\c$ /USER:vitas-server\administrator`, or try using the IP address in place of the server name, which can work better or worse in certain circumstances

Comment: those machines are on one LAN, so I don't use VPN. But before that they were in different locations and I was using Wireguard and I remember that this was happening exactly the same way. Maybe mapping the drive with vitas-server\administrator can have some effect... I will try that

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `.bat` script on the desktop that will
refresh the network shares, that you could run as a solution
when this situation happens.

Here is a script for one such share that you could use as a
template. It tests the existence of the share mapped a `X:`
and deletes it, then creates it anew:

```
@echo off
if exist x:\. net use x: /del /yes
if not exist x:\. net use x: \\server\share\ /persistent:yes
```

Comment: yes that would be a workaround. But I wonder what causes this error 1219 if I keep using the same account... if there is no explanation then I will have to do this

Comment: Error 1219 means multiple connections to the same share. My guess would be that the disconnected shares, while still staying in Windows, blocked Windows itself from re-connecting to the shares. This is why the only forceful solution besides reboot seems to be deleting these connections in order to clean up and then recreate to connect again.